# Mystery of Zoom auto-restarting, how do I stop it?

Tags: systemd, process, autostart

I'm running an ordinary Debian system on which I have installed Zoom.

After using Zoom, and quitting, the program keeps restarting. After
I kill it I use `ps` to check and it is gone, after about 15 minutes it
returns, I kill it again, and later it returns... When it restarts it always has a ppid of 1 (init).

I have checked `cron`, `init.d`, `systemd` and all my dot files and there is no trace of anything that can restart Zoom. What can be doing it? How does it do it?

I know it's not really a big deal but it is driving me mad and I want to understand how it happens *and* I would like it to disappear except when I want to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Could be xscreensaver trying to start its "zoom" screen saver when running in its "Random Screen Saver" mode. Configuring xscreensaver to never use its zoom screen saver worked for me. Further details:

http://zarnovican.github.io/2018/05/20/autostarting-zoom-app/

Comment: Interesting. I'll try this and see whether that makes any difference...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Zoom installed, so I can't check myself. But a quick Google gave me this link [How to disable Ibus autostart? (Which is a prerequisite of Zoom)](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/539741-How-to-disable-Ibus-autostart). Maybe the suggestions there will help you.

Comment: Thank you, that was interesting, ibus has been installed on my system by zoom but there is no ibus-autostart, I am going to keep looking...